# How to convert a string in binary form to a binary string in python

Tags: python-3.x, binary

As part of a compression project, I'm trying to convert a string in binary form, e.g. `"1000110"` to binary form to write directly to a binary file without the use of any external libraries.

The problem I'm experiencing is that with the `bytes()` or `bytearray()` or any other native functions I know of convert each digit into 2 bits, when I would like to store each bit as one bit.

Example test code:

```
with open(FILE+"testbin.bin", "wb+") as f:
    s = bytearray(list(map(int, "11011000")))

    f.write(s)
```

File contents in HexEditor:
`01 01 00 01 01 00 00 00`

Desired output:
`11 01 10 00`

Similarly I would need a method to reverse this process, i.e. converting a binary string to a string while keeping the data the same.

I'm sure I have missed something obvious here, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: >Desired output: `11 01 10 00` ... those are hexadecimal digits (base 16), not binary (base 2).

Comment: given "11011000", int("11011000") -> 11011000